# Layer up_sampling2d:<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.UpSampling2D'> is not supported

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, quantization-aware-training

I am trying to implement UNet for Semantic Segmentation that can run on Google Coral edgetpu. In order to do so, we need to have a quantized model that can be obtained using the tensorflow_model_optimization API.

But while using the API, there is a layer for UpSampling2D which is not supported by the [Quantization Aware API](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_comprehensive_guide). Here is the code to obtain a quantized model from a normal one as recommended.

```
from image_segmentation_keras.keras_segmentation.models.unet import vgg_unet 
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot 
model = vgg_unet(n_classes=4 ,  input_height=832, input_width=1216  ) 
quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model #q_aware stands for for quantization aware. 
q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)

...
o = (Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='valid' , data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
o = (BatchNormalization())(o)
o = Activation('relu')(o)

o = (UpSampling2D((2, 2), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
o = (concatenate([o, f3], axis=MERGE_AXIS))
o = (ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
...

Layer up_sampling2d:<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.UpSampling2D'> is not supported.You can quantize this layer by passing a `tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig` instance to the `quantize_annotate_layer` API.
```

Following are the findings-

- I tried using the alternative to up_sampling2d Conv2DTranspose instead of upsampling but it looks like Conv2DTranspose is also not supported.
- `Layer conv2Dtranspose:<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose'> is not supported.`
- Most of the [official example quantized models](https://github.com/google-coral/tflite/tree/master/python) of Edge TPU do not need upscaling of the image.E.g - Classification and Detection Models output is either a class or a number of bounding boxes with the respective classes.
- Although there is an example edgetpu quantization model for segmentation- [Deeplabv3 based quantized edgetpu segmentation](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/blob/master/test_data/deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_quant_edgetpu.tflite), there is no help regarding the architecture and how the upscaling has been solved.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm  not able to give you an answer to your question, but I do want to point out that upsampling2d is also not supported with the compiler: https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#supported-operations

I believe the issue here is just that the this ops has not been supported for tflite conversion yet.

Comment: Did you finally solve that in anyway?

Comment: No, but follow it on https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/issues/372?notification_referrer_id=MDE4Ok5vdGlmaWNhdGlvblRocmVhZDgzODMyNjIzOTo2NzQwMTE1#issuecomment-649773633

Comment: Any news on this?